# Why I have to press on back button twice to go back in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react App after I open a pop up (which changes the search object of useHistory())

It adds a query parameter of the search to the URL. **(ex: [www.example.com?query=value](http://www.example.com?query=value))**

Then when I close the pop up I clear the search history object:

```
const history = useHistory();
history.replace({ search: '' });
```

But after I close the pop up and presses on the back button, I have to press on it twice in order to back.

I want to press on back once to back not twice. (the normal way)

Comment: If you use `history.push(...)` when opening the popup, followed by `history.replace(...)` on close, you have created an additional navigation action (the first `push()`), which needs to be navigated over when using `history.back()`. Therefore it takes two browser-back actions to take you to the spot you were on before opening the popup.

Comment: I use <Link to={{ search: '?query=value' }}>example</Link> not history.push(...)

Comment: @SaschaM78 <Link to={{ search: '?query=value' }}> acts similar to history.push(...) when i used an onlick that has history.replace(...) it fixed it

My problem has been resolved, you could add this solution so i accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear you could solve the issue! I wrote an answer below, have a look if the text makes sense to you and fits your implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @SaschaM78 You could edit the answer so others know the problem more clearly by clearing out that: 

Using history.push(...)  or <Link to={{ search: '?query=value' }}> when opening the popup creates additional navigation action on the stack. Which will lead to multiple history.back() 

solved by using history.replace() in the onclick in the Link component instead of  to={{ search: '?query=value' }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `history.push(...)` or `<Link to={{ search: '?query=value' }}>` when opening the popup creates additional navigation action on the stack, which will lead to having to use multiple `history.back()`s.

Issue was solved by using `history.replace(...)` to change the page's location instead of forwarding the user via `<Link to={{ search: '?query=value' }}>` and then altering the history afterwards.